# Why is enthought mkl routine slower than matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I am testing the speed of linear algebra runtines of python enthought distribution which claims to be linked with intel MKL on windows platform. I did in IPython interactive shell the following:

```
import scipy.linalg as la
import numpy.random
M = random.rand(1000,1000)
%timeit la.svd(M);
```

`svd()` took typically 1.3 seconds. However if I use matlab R2011a, and did `M=rand(1000);tic;svd(M);toc`, it only takes typically 0.68 seconds.

I have seen similar previous questions comparing MKL and ATLAS or some other non-MKL build of scipy against MKL used by matlab. But my situation here should be exactly a comparison between MKL called by python and MKL called by matlabR2011a. So I am completely clueless why the results are so different. This is so discouraging for migrating to python from matlab.

By the way the version of MKL used by enthough is 10.3.1 while the one for matlab R2011a is 10.2.6.

Answer (score 8):

Numpy's `la.svd(M)` is calculating U, S, and V, while Matlab's `svd(M)` is calculating only S. Try comparing to `la.svd(M, compute_uv=False)` or `[U,S,V]=svd(M)`.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. This should be the reason. When I used la.svd(M, compute_uv=False) the time cost reduces to 0.5~0.6 seconds which is almost same as in matlab. When I compared la.svd(M) and [U S V]=svd(M) python takes ~1.1 seconds and matlab takes ~1.07, quite close to each other. Can I say that this minute difference is due to  that python has a higher overhead in allocating/managing memory space and related stuff?